# HTTP put and get(id) request ReactQuery

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, frontend, react-query

I change the redux in my project to ReactQuery,and i got some problem with put req in my code.
this is my code

```
const { dispatch } = store;

const editClientDataAsync = async ( id,data ) => {
    await axiosObj().put(`clients/${id}`,data);

}

const { mutateAsync: editClientData, isLoading } = useMutation(['editClientData'], editClientDataAsync, {
    onSuccess: () => dispatch({ type: SUCCESS_DATA, payload: { message: "Success" } }),
    onError: () => dispatch({ type: ERROR_DATA, payload: { message: "Error" } })
});
return { editClientData, isLoading }
```

}

same problem with when i try to get some req with id

```
const id = useSelector((state) => state?.clientData?.clientInfo?.data.id)



const getClientDetails = async ({ queryKey }) => {
    const [_, { id }] = queryKey;
    console.log(queryKey)
    if (!id)
        return;

    const { data } = await axiosObj().get(`clients/${id}`)
    console.log(data)
    return data;


}

const { data: clientDetails, isLoading } = useQuery(['ClientId', { id }], getClientDetails)

return { clientDetails, isLoading }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Mutation functions only take 1 argument

Check where you use the `editClientData` mutation and pass the arguments in one object.

```js
const editClientDataAsync = async ({ id, data }) => {
  await axiosObj().put(`clients/${id}`,data);
}

return useMutation(['editClientData'], editClientDataAsync, ...);
```

2. Are you sure you get an `id` passed to the function?

You can disable the query until you get that id with the `enabled` option, so you don't make an unnecessary http call.

```js
const id = useSelector((state) => state?.clientData?.clientInfo?.data.id)

const getClientDetails = async (id) => {
  const { data } = await axiosObj().get(`clients/${id}`)

  return data;
}

return useQuery(['client', id], () => getClientDetails(id), { enabled: !!id })
```

[Disable/pausing queries](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/disabling-queries)